# Native queries support Spring data jpa stream for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We need to retrieve data from SQL Server using Spring data jpa.

Being we have millions of records, we cannot load all data at one request. Is it possible to stream using the native queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make your query method return a Stream type in Spring Data JPA and still use native queries:

```java
@Query(value = "YOUR QUERY", nativeQuery = true)
Stream<YourRecordType> findAllRecords();
```

Rembember to close the Stream resource once you finish consuming from it, as recommended in the Spring Data JPA docs:

> A Stream potentially wraps underlying data store-specific resources
>   and must, therefore, be closed after usage. You can either manually
>   close the Stream by using the close() method or by using a Java 7
>   try-with-resources block (...)

Here are the relevant [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming) and an [example](https://github.com/Ro4052/grad-library-project/blob/03755e147aecd0dd894f04fe20fa4285f9dfcfed/src/main/java/com/scottlogic/librarygradproject/Repositories/BorrowRepository.java#L22).

Comment: My Actual question was will that support when i retrieve from sql server using native query

Comment: Yes, if you use Hibernate as your JPA provider you are able to retrieve from SQL server (including native queries). [Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-dialect) is the full list of database dialects supported by Hibernate.

Comment: Appreciate your response..that answers my question