# Will a Spring JPA Repository Native Query returning a Stream using Hibernate over SQL Server lazy-load the collection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, java-stream

I'm picking a up a project where there is a JpaRepository implementation that uses a native query in Spring on top of hibernate and SQL Server which returns a List. The query does not having paging or limits implemented. I'm worried this will cause a problem in production if it loads the full result set into memory.

Example:

```java
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity,String> {
...
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
  value = "SELECT t.name, t.date FROM MY_TABLE t WHERE t.condition = true")
List<MyEntity> getAll();
```

The code that consumes this List uses the Stream API so I could refactor the method to return a Stream but I cannot find any documentation that indicates if this will lazy-load to avoid fetching the whole result set at once.

Will that work? Or do I need to refactor this do to proper paging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Native queries support Spring data jpa stream for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352590/native-queries-support-spring-data-jpa-stream-for-sql-server)

Comment: I doubt it answers (your production considerations), but it shows how (easy is) to  `Stream<SomeEntity>` in spring-data. Of course you should "analyze your query plan", ...load, capacities, bottlenecks, cache ... before moving to production

Comment: @xerx593 thanks but no, I am particularly concerned about it loading a full result set which that does not address

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stream Api to lazy load from database without breaking your memory but to make this work you need to do the following :

Annotate your query with these hints :

```
 @QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE),
        @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
        @QueryHint(name = READ_ONLY, value = "true")
})
@Query(nativeQuery = true, "SELECT t.name, t.date FROM MY_TABLE t WHERE t.condition = true")
Stream<MyEntity> getAll();
```

This will disable second level caching and return read only record.

Then to use your query you need to provid it in a transactional block :

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public void process() {
    Stream<MyEntity> myEntityStream = myEntityRepo.getAll();
  
    myEntityStream .forEach(entity-> {
      // do some processing
     entityManager.detach(entity);
    });
  }
```

Note at the end I detach entity to let the garbage collector free memory

Comment: Interesting. The extra annotations and detach aren't ideal. I don't think I would want that repeated as a pattern in the codebase. However I'll accept if a better answer doesn't come along. Thanks.