Heap memory grows uncontrollably when generating large data Streams
I am trying to generate an Excel file using a Java Stream and SXSSFWorkbook for memory efficiency. My goal is to handle large datasets with a heap size limit of 2GB. However, despite trying to flush rows and manage memory, the heap usage keeps growing until it runs out of memory. To sake of semplicity, I did a test using a temporary file to write the data and returning nothing.
This is my code:
public String extractInformationAndGenerateExcel(String username, List<String> comuniList, String uniqueFileName) throws IOException {
        

        Path tempFilePath = Files.createTempFile("temp_", ".txt");
        try (Stream<ContrattiAttrezzature> contrattiEAttrezzatureStream = contrattiAttrezzatureRepository.getReportContrattiAttrezzature(username, comuniList);
             ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFilePath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
            )
        {

            logger.info("Start to write file??????");
            contrattiEAttrezzatureStream.forEach(contratto -> {
                try {
                    writer.write(contratto.toString());  
                    writer.newLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            });
             logger.info("Finish");

            return "Finish?";
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }finally {
            
            if (tempFilePath != null && Files.exists(tempFilePath)) {
                try {
                    Files.delete(tempFilePath);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Error", e);
                }
            }
        }

    }

However, the memory usage continues to grow. I'm using these JVM settings: -Xmx2g -XX:+UseSerialGC. As you can see, the RAM is limited to 2GB and I can't increase it. My Driver is jdbc.SQLServerDriver and I use SQLServer2019Dialect with Java 1.8
My Situation using VisualVM is this

Here is an image of the thread profile of my Java application, showing the execution times and status of the various threads:

Questions:

Is the use of Stream correct?
Is there something I am not considering?

SOLUTION:
I am sad to see that Stackoverflow closed the question for me even though I edited it.
Nevertheless, I would like to bring the solution I found so that it can be of help to anyone with the same problem as me.
After searching for a long time I found this answer about the entity manager of the transaction. Basically the entity manager keeps all the references in memory and suggests to ‘clean up’ through a clean.
This is my code updated with an example
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager; // <-- new line
public String extractInformationAndGenerateExcel(String username, List<String> comuniList, String uniqueFileName) throws IOException {


        final int batchSize = 100; // <-- new line
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(); // <-- new line
        Path tempFilePath = Files.createTempFile("temp_", ".txt");
        try (Stream<ContrattiAttrezzature> contrattiEAttrezzatureStream = contrattiAttrezzatureRepository.getReportContrattiAttrezzature(username, comuniList);
             ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFilePath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
            )
        {

            logger.info("Start to write file??????");
            contrattiEAttrezzatureStream.forEach(contratto -> {
                try {
                    writer.write(contratto.toString());  
                    writer.newLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            });
            
            // clear the memory
            if (counter.incrementAndGet() % batchSize == 0) {
                entityManager.clear();
            }
             logger.info("Finish");

            return "Finish?";
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }finally {

            if (tempFilePath != null && Files.exists(tempFilePath)) {
                try {
                    Files.delete(tempFilePath);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Error", e);
                }
            }
        }

    }


How is SQL server relevant?

I'd probably move the whole Class and Field-thing outside of the loop, surely it can be done once? And bin the stream, it's a waste of unnecessary cycles, what's wrong with a list of array. Of course, that might not be the issue here. forEach is a bit dangerous too, you'd probably want forEachOrdered but i can be wrong. ALso, how's stream generated? Are you sure you aren't holding some kind of resultset at the bottom of it? SQL Server has some buffering strategies which might be useful to avoid holding too much rows in memory

@DaleK  don't know if I understood the question correctly. I mentioned SQL server because from a series of Googles some people say it may be related to the driver used. If you are referring to whether it is SQL server is replaceable with something else, the answer is no: I cannot replace it.

@siggemannen I use the stream instead of the List (as it was originally) because from this answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/61353428/4700162 I saw that the stream is used to process large amounts of data by taking them a little at a time. Also, how can I check whether I have any ResultSets active? Can you give me some example?

Ok, but how do you populate it? and how big is your source data? I'd also look at the heap dump and see which classes / objects dominate size-wise when you get OOM. Your excel code looks ok, i myself use SXSSFWorkbook with good success

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); - this seems fishy to me. Even if you fetch the data from db in batches, when you write it after computations, everything stays in memory.

@Chaosfire But this should happen when I have finished processing all the data. I do not ‘return’ a workbook, but it stops in the iteration. Am I mistaken?

Wait, do you return a copy of your excel file? Maybe that's the problem. Why not use FileOutputStream and save the data there

@siggemannen What do you mean by returning a copy of Excel? No, in the end I return an array of bytes to be uploaded to cloude. The download is done with another API. However the dataset we are talking about is about 1 mln. The data is taken from the query (which is very very large) and you want to process it to define the excel. At the end of the generateExcelStream method I return a Workbook (perhaps you are referring to this) but I repeat that I crash during processing. I have tried generating a dump, but they are generic classes.

@siggemannen can you give me a little bit example? I want to try not to pass him the stream as a parameter, maybe this will bother him

You could create a temporary file with File.createTempFile, then use FileOUtputStream (with or without bufferstream) to write to that file and return the filename which the caller can use to upload the data into the cloud. This should allevate some memory pressure

Don't return a byte[] as that will copy all things to memory. Easiest is to pass an outputstream or writer into the method to directly write to. Of write to a (temporary) File and pass that around but that might not be allowed (or run into space issues as wel) depending on your environment.

I updated my question. The problem is not related byte[] or excel but, instead, is related to Stream process
